# Date not being found in data range

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to to send an email every week and include information from a sheet in the email content. However the date is not searching correctly even though I have the date and the logs show the text matching exactly.

This is for a weekly program that volunteers can sign up on the sheet. The purpose of this is to remind any who wish to sign up to do so and provide the information on how to do that.

```
function sendEmails() {
  var signupSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("volunteers");
  var upcomingSunday = new Date(Date.now() + 5*1000*60*60*24);
  upcomingSunday.setHours(0,0,0,0)
  Logger.log(upcomingSunday);
  var currentWeekRow = findRowByValue(signupSheet,upcomingSunday);
  Logger.log(currentWeekRow);
  if (signupSheet.getRange(currentWeekRow,2).getValues() = ""){
    var chairman = "Chairman";
    }
    else{
    var chairman = "";
  }
}
function findRowByValue(sheet,value){
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("A1:A");
  var values = dataRange.getValues();
  Logger.log(values);
  Logger.log(value);
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {     
      if (values[i][j] == value) {
        Logger.log(i);
        return i+1;
      }
    }    
   }
  return -1;
}
```

I expect the findRowByValue function to return the row with the date for upcomingSunday, but it keeps returning -1 which indicates it isn't finding it, however the log shows that it is there.

Comment: This `if (signupSheet.getRange(currentWeekRow,2).getValues() = ""){` should be something like this: `if (signupSheet.getRange(currentWeekRow,2).getValue() == ""){` It's also better to do this `sheet.getRange("1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),1);` instead of this: ``sheet.getRange("A1:A");  Not sure what setting chairman has to do with sending an email.

Comment: This is not necessary `for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {     
      if (values[i][j] == value) {
        Logger.log(i);
        return i+1;
      }
    }    
   }` Your range is only one column wide.

Comment: Thanks again. This is my first time doing anything with Google Apps Script so I'm still learning. The second part is supposed to identify the row that contains the date value. perhaps this is somehow looking for that incorrectly. I tried to search several places to find code that would work.

Comment: Look at the notes I added to my answer.   My code reads all of the data on the page and searches for the next Sunday in column 1 which vA[i][0] in my code.  I just thought it would be easier to get colum1 data and column2 data at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function sendEmails() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName("volunteers");
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();//This gets the range that has all of the data on the sheet and column one is the date according to your code
  var vA=rg.getValues();//this gets the data 
  var chairman="";
  var nextSunday=getNextSunday();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {//vA[i][0] is column 1
    if(new Date(vA[i][0]).valueOf()==nextSunday.valueOf()) {//compare milliseconds to milliseconds
      if(vA[i][1]=="") {//this is column 2
        chairman="Chairman";
        //not sure what this has to do with send email
        //probably want to break here
        break;
      } 
    }
  }

}

function getNextSunday() {//This finds the next sunday based upon the current date
  var t=new Date();
  while(t.getDay()!=0) {
    t.setDate(t.getDate()+1);
  }
  t.setHours(0,0,0,0);//set time to midnight
  return t;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. The chairman is just 1 of 6 almost identical roles shown in this code. They are each filled out in a spreadsheet and i am looking to see when they are blank and if so include them in the email. if they are not blank then i need to say that that role is still needed. I did not see in your above code how it would determine the cell value for the cell which is to contain the chairman info. This is really where my code is having trouble as since the date is not recognized in the data the row comes through as -1 instead of the correct row.

Comment: Thanks! The comments really helped. I got my code working perfectly now.